# npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found: create-install@latest

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, npm-install

I keep having issues trying to install vue with npm. The errror above pops up when I enter npm init install vue. 
If I run npm install vue, I get the following issue:

```
npm WARN patrikkozak@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN patrikkozak@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ vue@2.6.11
updated 1 package and audited 1 package in 1.017s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I need help, thank you!

Comment: it doesnt seem like an error just a warning

Comment: I can't answer for sure why it's happening but i suggest you make sure you have installed node and the vue cli properly.

Comment: If you want to install `vue` you must run `npm install vue`, `npm init install vue` is wrong see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init#description about `npm init`.

Comment: `npm WARN patrikkozak@1.0.0 No description npm WARN patrikkozak@1.0.0 No repository field ` => This just warning that your package.json doesn't have repository field which is fine. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository

Comment: @User28 Thanks for the info and response. I'm trying npm install -g @vue/cli and now I'm getting multiple permission errors.

Comment: @chs242 I believe node is installed properly but I'm trying to install vue/cli with "npm install -g @vue/cli and I am getting multiple permission errors and I don't know why.

Comment: @User28 I posted a second question regarding the permission issues, so there is more info there...